# php, activating registration through email. How to minimize database searching cost

Tags: php, email, registration

The process is pretty simple.

After the user fills up fields for registration, a column i.e. 'activation_key' in the mysql database table keeps a randomly generated long string, another column i.e. `activated` holds the value 0.

An activation email is sent to the registrant's email with the activation link that contains the random key value of the `activation_key` column. Upon clicking the link, the url searches  the database for the `activation_key'`columncontaining the long string`.`If there is any such value,then the 'activation_key` is set to blank and the 'activated' column is set to 1.

When the  activation key string is generated , a search is made to see whether the key being generated already exists and if it does exist, another random value is generated to get a unique one.

So when a few would-be members have their registration pending , then the similar string search is actually performed on their rows in the table.

**Up to this point, everything is ok.**

But just think that a new member gets an activation string that was previously generated for another member who completed the registration .

If by any chance the already-registered member clicks on the activation link in his/her old
email, then the other new member will get his/her registration completed even when s/he has not completed the registration actually.

SO I decided not to set the 'activation_key' table to blank and therefore the similar string search took place for all the already or would-be members.

That is fine. But if the number of users is big  i.e. more than 1 lac, then the registration process to send the activation email will take much time.

1) Any other way to minimize the database exploration cost?

2) What policy does mega site like facebook take in this case?

Comment: Use functions that generate unique id like http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php or add an index on the activation_key column to speed up searches for a value.

Comment: how to add an index on the activation_key column to speed up searches? Explain please. How will the mentioned php function help- just cannot understand.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a very small chance of generating the same activation key twice. But the solution would be sending the activation key **and** the username in the e-mail, and check the database against both.

So when the activation e-mail is sent out, it contains a link to

```
/activate.php?activation_key=key&username=name
```

instead of just the `activation_key`. And when checking whether the key is real or not, you do

```
WHERE activation_key = key AND username = name;
```

in the mysql query.

So this way, you safeguard the system so that both the username and the key is required to properly activate the user.

To ensure more safety, you can make a `UNIQUE` index on the `activation_key` column. When the script attempts to add the generated key to the row of the user, using an already existing one, the query execution will fail because the column is set to be unique. You just then need to modify the script to try generating a key until it is successfully stored in the database. **Make sure you don't let it go infinite looping.**

### Infinite loop protection

```
$count = 0;
while ( $errno === 0 )
{
    // mySQL query here
    $errno = mysql_errno();

    $count++;

    if ( $count >= 5 )
            $errno = -1;
}

if ( $errno === -1 )
    echo "Sorry, the script was unable to generate the token for your activation.";
```

This cycle will run the query (which adds the activation token to the database) you put there until the query executes without an error. With each execution `$count` is increased, and if it reaches the limit (5 in the example), it will force the loop to end (setting `$errno` to a non-zero but not real mySQL error value), and displaying an error message to the user afterwards.

Comment: let me think about the solution

Comment: why to  add the UNIQUE index? I check for the uniqueness of the key when I generate it. I use 'id' as the primary key. So I can use `id` instead of `username` in the link.

Comment: How to make sure that I don't let that go for  infinite looping?

Comment: You said you fear that if someone, already-activated uses a key which is now referenced to another user, the already-activated person might accidentally activate someone else's registration.

Comment: You do a loop which runs until the generated key is a new one, so if tried to added into the database, it is not returned an error. You need to create a counter variable which records how many *attempts* were made on generating the token, and if it exceeds a number, like 5 or 10, you force the halt of execution.

Comment: a bit more about `halt of execution. ` please?

Comment: I have edited the answer so that the loop protection is there.

Comment: So, did it work? If it did, you should accept this answer so if someone searches your problem and arrives here, he/she will see what to do.

Comment: will make the  decision soon. Thanks for your sense.

Answer (score 0):

Store the Data of new registered and not activated accounts in a seperate table.

As you propably won't need more then basic information on the inactive users, you can keep unnessecary data, e.g. profile settings, out of it.

Once the activation key is sent, check this table for an entry with the corresponding key. If it is found, tranfer the date to the real user table and delete the entry from the table with users that wait for activation.

In this way, you can:
a) save space as an activated user doesen't need the key anymore
b) get a quicker overview over the users which haeven't been activated.

You should also combine this with a cron deleting users that have not been activated for 3 days or so in my opinion ;-)

Comment: important part of my question begins here  -'If by any chance the already-registered member clicks on the activation link in his/her old email, then the other new member will get his/her registration completed even when s/he has not completed the registration actually.' Go on reading till end. I did not understand anything related with this part in  your answer .

Comment: Okay, I fogot the importent stuff ^^ I guess you cannot have two users with the same ID/Username. Just add the username into the activation link and check for it. Only if kay and Username match, the user can be activated. The chances that there are users who have the same Name AND same key is pretty low ;-)

Comment: Please have a look at what I said in my comment to Emil Vikström.

Answer (score 0):

Include the user id and possibly the e-mail address or username in the activation link. Possible advantages:

- You can do an integer search on the user id
- You don't need to worry about duplicate activation links
- You don't need to index the activation_key field, because you're not going to search on it anyway
- When including the e-mail (or username), nobody will be able to "try" all userids in order to activate those that have a duplicate of the activation_key
- It will be really hard, or impossible, to bruteforce the activation_keys to activate all users.
- You don't have to worry about data races on the activation_key.

Important: Don't just use the e-mail address and a short activation_key. Make sure it's close to impossible to bruteforce the activation key for a certain e-mail address.

Comment: yes, that can be the `id` (primary key of the table) and the activation string to build the link, right? In that case, do I really need to generate a unique string for the activation key? If yes, even in that case, if the number of incomplete registration is big, it might cost much to search in the db. Any solution please?

Comment: Indexing speeds up the serch in the db a lot, also you could split your tables by, for example, the first letter(s) of the username. For example for a-d, e-h, and so on. On the other hand, this would result in much more sql queries to the db if you want to display everything. Do you already know how big your project will be in the end? I can't imagine that you need to think that precisely about optimization if it's not gonna be something equal to an international social network in size.

Comment: @Corsair, that is a bit like a social networking site aimed at a certain group of people. Not sure how many people it can attract.. Let us suppose 10,000. Can you tell a bit more about splitting the table programmatically ?

Comment: 10.000? Okay, even if there are gonna be about a million I think that indexing is enough. I did a project on hashtabes containing over a billion of entries and the respone times were not that bad using mysql indexing. Keep in mind that the performance is also affected by the statements you use to query the db, do you need all of the 50 collums or just 3? As long as you have user counts < 100.000, don't think that much about (propably immature) optimization. And I meant physical splitting the table - different tables for specific data traits. But this should only be used for huge data amounts.